# Creating matrices in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.4

I've tried different ways but I can't understand why I cannot create a matrix in numpy.

I get a "TypeError: **new**() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given" error when I call:

```
def createGST(dictionary):
    x = int(dictionary['x'])
    y = int(dictionary['y'])
    z = int(dictionary['z'])
    matrix = np.matrix( (str(1),str(0),str(0),str(x)),(str(0),str(1),str(0),str(y)),(str(0),str(0),str(1),str(z)),(str(0),str(0),str(0),str(1)) )
    return matrix
```

It did not work even without the typecasting to str().
I'm using python 3.4.

Comment: Give a sample of what you want.   Clearly you are missing a set of [] or ().  But why the `str`?  What is that supposed to do?  Do you want a matrix of numbers or strings?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why _are_ you converting to strings? Really, the only reason to use a matrix instead of just a 2D array is to have more convenient access to matrix-math operations, and none of those operations make any sense on strings.

Comment: `np.matrix` does accept a string input: `np.matrix('1,2,3;4,5,6')`.  That's meant to emulate MATLAB, and isn't commonly used.

Comment: This was resolved, apparently I was missing an inner set of parathesis between np.matrix( and (str(1)...

I thought I followed the examples and documentation I found correctly but I was wrong. 

For those curious, I decided that I might have to typecast to string because I found an example using np.array('1','2',..) as it's syntax. I am also trying to replace what I use matlab for by using scipy since I no longer have a student license to matlab.

Comment: where did you find an example that used `np.array('1', '2', . . . )`?  that's just plain wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right in the error message.  You're passing five parameters to `np.matrix`:

```
matrix = np.matrix((str(1), str(0), str(0), str(x)),
                   (str(0), str(1), str(0), str(y)),
                   (str(0), str(0), str(1), str(z)),
                   (str(0), str(0), str(0), str(1)))
```

`np.matrix` does not take five parameters.  This is what you meant to do:

```
matrix = np.matrix(((str(1), str(0), str(0), str(x)),
                    (str(0), str(1), str(0), str(y)),
                    (str(0), str(0), str(1), str(z)),
                    (str(0), str(0), str(0), str(1))))
```

Notice the extra parentheses.

Comment: AH so I see. I thought I was using the right number. I swear the documentation I've found is all on 2.7 or poor examples. Thanks mate!

Comment: no problem.  but it's the same in 2.7 as it is in 3.4: you need to enclose the rows in a list, tuple, or other sequence before passing them to `matrix`.  is there anything i can do to improve my answer for you?  if not, would you mind accepting it?  this would show other users that this question has been resolved.

Comment: but, actually, i think i see what you mean.  it looks to me like you're passing four parameters -- the four rows -- yet the error says you're passing five.  the error also says that `matrix` takes four parameters, but in the `matrix` docstring, only three parameters are listed.  i'm not sure what the deal is with that.  still, the key point is that all the data should be supplied as the first parameter -- not as one parameter per row.

Comment: I am new, how do I computer? (accept)
Figured it out. Thanks you guys!

It makes perfect sense now when I think about it. For some reason I either didn't read the right number of parenthesis or they weren't in the example. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error message about 4 parameters, a look at the `np.matrix` code shows why:

```
class matrix(N.ndarray):
    def __new__(subtype, data, dtype=None, copy=True):
    ....
```

`np.matrix([...],...)` creates an object of class `matrix`.  So it calls that class's `__new__`.  Normally object creation calls `__init__`, but there must be some nuance here that required the use of the underlying `__new__` instead.  In any case, you can see the 4 arguments that the error message mentions.  The first is automatic.  So that plus your four tuples makes 5.

If you are missing your MATLAB license, look at Octave.  It takes most of the same syntax.  Still, welcome to Python and numpy.

`np.matrix` can make things look, and work more like MATLAB, but an older version (e.g. 3.5).  You are restricted to 2d. In general the basic `np.array` is more useful.